# Could not create folder. Try reconnecting or restarting your device

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, file-transfer, sony-xperia, file-management, macos

I am using a Xperia C4 with Mac OS X Yosemite.

I have Android File Transfer Installed.  It allows me to drag files over and transfer but it won't allow me to create folders or move folders across for transfer.

I have tried entering developer mode, rebooting, restarting device.  Nothing fixes it.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Is your Android phone unlocked (i.e. "swipe to unlock" or you have unlocked it) before trying to create/transfer the folder?

Comment: Yes, it is unlocked.  Normal files transfer fine, it just doesnt like me creating folder or moving folders.

Comment: Mind if I ask what Android File Transfer program you are using?

Comment: @Ankush , in this case there is only one common Android File Transfer program. It is the standard one recommended by Google to communicate with Android devices via MTP. In short, basically the app is a MTP Client.

Comment: Could the OP try updating his AFT app? That could help. Also, although this may be a bit rash, if it is possible, could the OP also update to El Capitan? I heard somewhere that that **may** help.

Comment: I have updated the app but I'd rather find a solution that upgrade my OS.  Last time I upgraded my development environment got messed up.